# Question authors can prevent their question from reaching the suggested edit review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

With [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7610692) I removed some unnecessary tags from the title of the question, and I removed the "thanks" from the end.

The rest of the post was fine, normally this edit should pass review.

Why is it the question author (who has a low reputation level and no edit privileges) has the right to summarily reject the edit suggestion without it going through the suggested edits review queue, where it will get reviewed by more experienced members?

<sup>*There is no disrespect to the question author, the rest of the question was fine. But as we all know tags in the title and thanks at the bottom are both actively discouraged.*</sup>

Comment: You say: _"But as we all know tags in the title..."_, but as a new user, they probably don't know that. It would probably be better in such cases to comment to the user stating this with a link to the relevant help pages and expanding the edit comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post's owner has a binding vote when reviewing suggested edits, and the ability to review these regardless of their reputation level.

That's just the way it is.

Quoting from [FAQ on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/158001):

> The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post.