# What must happen for a user with a 50 rep to be asked to approve an edit of their post?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have successfully edited a few questions already. But I saw something different today. The final "approved," vote (that actually caused the entire edit to be approved) came from the OP (who had a 50 rep).

What is going on there? Did he get a "special invite" by a moderator or a super user? If so, why? What are the guidelines and the rules for that action?

Comment: AFAIK: If you edit a post from another person he gets a notification, which when he clicks on it brings up the review window. And if OP approves it, it will be automatically "approved".

Comment: The OP is always able to edit their own posts.  This also means their "reviews" of suggestions are binding.  The accepted answer for this post, answers your question: [Question authors can prevent their question from reaching the suggested edit review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289652/question-authors-can-prevent-their-question-from-reaching-the-suggested-edit-rev), which is further linked to the [MSE faq for suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284)

Answer (score 6):

As an original poster, you receive notifications for edits to your own questions/answers.  Their vote is also binding on edits.

There aren't any rules per se; the only hope is that the OP isn't approving edits that detract from the original post.